# Using index in excel how to get a 6th value from a array

Tags: excel

I am trying to get 6th day from the day itself and should repeat for 3 times but I am not able to get the desired output

```
Column A  Column B(Expected output)
Sunday    Sunday
Monday    Friday
Tuesday   Wednesday
Wednesday Monday
Thursday  Saturday
Friday    Thursday
Saturday  Tuesday
          Sunday
          Wednesday
          Monday
          Saturday
          Thursday
          Tuesday
          Sunday
          Wednesday
          Monday
          Saturday
          Thursday
          Tuesday
          Sunday
```

I am using:

```
=INDEX($E$1:$E$7,6)
```

and I am getting only Friday and if I do auto fill only Friday is copied to all cells.

Any assistance much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to show the name of every sixth day from a starting date.  There are different approaches to that. The Index() one is a possibility, but not the easiest.

Easier: In the first cell (B1), enter the starting date. Format with custom format "dddd".
In the next cell down use a formula

```
=B1+5
```

and format with custom format "dddd". Copy down as far as desired.

OR use

```
=TEXT($B$1+((ROW()-1)*5),"dddd")
```

and copy down.

If you want to base this on today's date, you can start in B1 with

```
=TEXT(TODAY()+((ROW()-1)*5),"dddd")
```

and copy down.

EDIT: if the cell contents is not about dates and weekdays, but just any text or value, then you can use the Index() approach.  For an array with seven values, you want to extract every 6th value, looping through the seven values. That would mean that the values are accessed in the following order:

1
6
4
2
7
5
3

Therfore, you need a formula that delivers this number sequence. This formula, if started in row 1 and copied down, does that:

```
=(1+((ROW()-1)*5))-((INT((1+((ROW()-1)*5))/7)-IF(MOD((1+((ROW()-1)*5))/7,1),0,1))*7)
```

Wrap an Index around it and adjust your column references. In B1 and copied down to B21:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,(1+((ROW()-1)*5))-((INT((1+((ROW()-1)*5))/7)-IF(MOD((1+((ROW()-1)*5))/7,1),0,1))*7))
```

Comment: Thanks teylyn, may be my explanation is not clear enough. 
All I want is intially show A1 cell value in B1 and count 5 cells from there i.e A6 value should be shown in B2 and count 5 cells from there i.e A4 value should be shown in B3 and so on...

Comment: I think I understand that. If the cell values are weekdays, then my answer will deliver the result. If this is not about weekdays, please update your question.

Comment: Thanks teylyn, based on your solution I got desired output just changed a bit as follows in Cell A1 used =TODAY() and in B1 =TEXT(WEEKDAY($A$1),"dddd") and changed the format to custom "dddd" and then in B2 =TEXT($A$1+((ROW()-1)*5),"dddd") and there after I copied B2 to remaining cells to get the output.

Comment: I added another approach with Index().

Comment: Index formula is perfect for my problem, once again Thanks "=INDEX($A$1:$A$7,(1+((ROW()-1)*5))-((INT((1+((ROW()-1)*5))/7)-IF(MOD((1+((ROW()-1)*5))/7,1),0,1))*7))"